# SSRS Containing Group Labels

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, business-intelligence

I have a report which runs over multiple days and reports on 13 hours of data (07:00-20:00)

I have included an image below and as you can see the the date container starts before 7:00 and extends beyond the 20:00 mark.

I managed to get them to line up as I wanted but undid the changes and I have no idea how I did it.

What do I need to do?

[image: Date Group Label]

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a line graph with the Category Groups: Time, and Date.
You can also specifiy the Minimum and Maximum time range in Hours within the chart properties.

Comment: The maximum and minimum times are set in the query, I just need to know how to make the day container align properly with the hours when the rdl renders.

Comment: Yes so within the report builder. For the Categories properties for Hours you would have that by Interval of 1. For the hours you would set the properties to date, by interval of 1.